# Add content type filter to existing view programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I'm fairly new to Views and wanted to modify an existing view programatically. This artcile helps [programmatically-set-a-views-filter-in-drupal-6-and-views-2](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/655/programmatically-set-a-views-filter-in-drupal-6-and-views-2), yet I have no idea how to customize it for my needs.

I need to modify a view and add a content type filter. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I just did this, adding a language filter to an existing view, programatically. Here's how I approached it.

In the views_ui interface (admin/build/views), select your view and add the filter through the web interface. Once you've got it set up correctly, export your view. You'll get a big array in php code. Find your filter within the array and copy-paste it into a temporary text file for future reference.

Now, in code, do this:

```
// Load the view by specifying its name (as displayed at admin/build/views
$view = views_get_view('name_of_view');
// Specify the display you are editing - you can see this at admin/build/views/edit/name_of_view.
// Usually it's something like 'page' or 'block' or 'default'
$display = 'default';
$view->view_set_display($display);
// Now load up an available filter. You must do this step - it's the equivalent of
// clicking 'add' in the interface.
// filter_name is the same as what is specified in your export from before. 
$filter_name = 'language';
$filter = $view->get_item($display, 'filter', $filter_name);
// Now set the arguments. This will need to match what is in your export from before...
$filter['value']['***CURRENT_LANGUAGE***'] = '***CURRENT_LANGUAGE***';
// ...and save the filter.
$view->set_item('default', 'filter', 'language', $filter);
```

This worked well for me. For reference, here's the relevant extract of my views export:

```
'language' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
'value' => array(
  '***CURRENT_LANGUAGE***' => '***CURRENT_LANGUAGE***',
),
'group' => '0',
'exposed' => FALSE,
'expose' => array(
  'operator' => FALSE,
  'label' => '',
),
'id' => 'language',
'table' => 'node',
'field' => 'language',
'override' => array(
  'button' => 'Override',
),
 'relationship' => 'none',
),
```

Comment: Cam, what hook function did you do the above in?

Comment: I did it in a hook_install implementation, so that a view on our live site was updated correctly on deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your best bet is to use [hook_views_query_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--docs.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/6) to add a `WHERE` to limit to a particular `node.type`.  You can examine `$view` to determine whether your view in question is being called, and then use the `$query` object to add the constraint.  Unfortunately, the views hooks are sparsely documented, and you often need to look at the actual module source to see what is really happening.